# How to Determine if "200 OK" is Really a Misconfigured ASP.NET MVC Custom 404 Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, web-scraping, libcurl

tl;dr: Misconfigured ASP.NET MVC servers return "200 OK" when they should 404.

I'm building [a list of tech employeer career page links](http://www.warplife.com/jobs/computer/).  I am flummoxed to find it quite common that such companies have open positions listed on their sites, but they don't have any links to them.  That is, if you visit www.example.com, nowhere on the homepage - sometimes, nowhere on the whole website - can be found a link to www.example.com/jobs

To get around that, after manually indexing a few hundred sites, I made a list of common URL paths:

```
 /careers
 /careers/
 /careers.html
 /jobs.aspx
```

I have written a straightforward python script that when given a list of company homepages, uses pycurl - a wrapper around libcURL - to attempt HTTP HEAD requests for each (homepage, urlpath) pair:

```
http://www.example.com/careers
http://www.example.com/jobs
http://www.example.net/careers
http://www.example.net/jobs
```

This mostly works.

However there is what I gather to be a common misconfiguration problem with ASP.NET MVC which results in custom 404 pages producing a 200 response code while displaying the custom "Not Found" page.  For example

```
http://www.microsoft.com/bill-gates-is-the-spawn-of-satan.html
```

Yes, that's right folks: Microsoft misconfigured their own server.  :-D

If you use Firefox' web developer tools you can see that the above link produces a 200 OK instead of a 404 Not Found.

I expect this is a common problem for anyone who deals with scraping or robots: is there a straightforward programmatic way that I could tell that the above link *should* produce a 404 instead of a 200?

In my particular case, a modestly unsatisfactory solution would be to note that none of my links produce 404s, then produce a "can't find" output.  In such cases I manually google the careers pages:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=site:microsoft.com+careers
```

My goal for the near term is to partially automate the discovery of the links for my tech employer index.  I expect that *fully* automating it would be intractible; I hope to automate the easy stuff.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your microsoft example. I tried curl, chrome and firefox and all of them returned 404-status. Could you have some bugs in your python script maybe?

Comment: For me, `curl -i http://www.microsoft.com/bill-gates-is-a-philanthropist.html` gives an `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` including `<title>We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.</title>`.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the user-agent.  I'll look into it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way from the client end to know that a page is invalid when the server is explicitly telling the client that the page *is* valid. The second best solution that I can come up with is to grep for common text that is usually displayed on such pages such as "sorry" and "not found". This will, of course, do nothing for you if the custom error page is actually a redirect to a completely valid page such as the home page.